# facebook news feed not showing up on website

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api

i am working on a website for an animal shelter and  they wanted me to add there facebook feed to the website so i used  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin and it is not showing up at all on my website in my sidebar. cna anyone help me figure out whats wrong.
                  the css

```
  body

 {

background-image: url('bg.jpg');

}
  #wrapper
{
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  #sidebar
   {
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 55px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.48);
    border: 1px rgba(45, 45, 45, 1) solid;
    }
  #main-news
  {
    position: absolute;
    left: 210px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 55px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.48);
    border: 1px rgba(45, 45, 45, 1) solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

  #main-content-news
 {
    bottom: 100px;
    padding: 100px;
 }
 #box
  {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 130px;
  }
 #footer {
width:100%;
height:20px;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
left:0;
 }
  div.footer {
  position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 padding: 0rem;
 background-color: #000000;
 text-align: center;
}
```

[the code](http://pastebin.com/Bm7EsLFs)

sorry for the paste bin i had trouble formatting the code

Comment: where we will check your code?

Comment: check the browser console for warnings/errors

Comment: do you need to post the css?

Comment: @ahmdabos the html code is on paste bin just click the text called 'the code'

Comment: @luschn ill check the console for error and get back to you.

Comment: @alexoaklel i dont think i need to but i will.